# How can I use the Angular HttpClient to write e2e tests for my backend api?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-e2e

I want to write some tests for my back-end api.  Because my front-end is Angular, I already have a complete testing framework in my environment and thought it would be good to use this rather than importing and learning something new (if I was doing unit-tests I'd need a native testing framework, but I just want to test the http interface here).

To avoid complicating my question, let's forget about my back-end and just use a public api ([People-In-Space](http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/People-In-Space/)) here instead.

It's easy to create a new app with the Angular CLI, add [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) and write a test:

**api.e2e-spec.ts**

```
import * as superagent from 'superagent';

describe('people-in-space API', () => {

    it('should report success getting a list of people in space', (done) => {
        superagent.get('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json').then((response: superagent.Response) => {
            expect(response.body.message).toEqual('success');
            done();
        }).catch(done.fail);
    });

});
```

This runs fine, and you can find it in [this repository](https://github.com/Antony74/people-in-space).

Now I'm happy to be talked out of any of this, but ideally I don't think I should be using superagent as my http-client because all the rest of my code will be using [Angular's HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient).

What exactly do I need to configure before I can rewrite the above test using HttpClient, please?

### What I've tried so far

You can find my attempt to solve the problem [here](https://github.com/Antony74/people-in-space/commit/26d184db84951e548c6932ce4c073aafd4e8fd5f).  I've:

- Written the test
- Added zone.js to my protractor.conf.js file
- Attempted to import the HttpClient module (and in doing so it looks like I've broken some other dependency)

The error I am getting is:

```
> people-in-space@0.0.0 e2e C:\git\people-in-space
> ng e2e

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49152, open your browser on http://localhost:49152/ **
[0mDate: [1m[37m2018-01-04T21:43:44.807Z[39m[22m[0m
[0mHash: [1m[37m6929b70a097b5cdc054b[39m[22m[0m
[0mTime: [1m[37m7234[39m[22mms[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33minline[39m[22m} [1m[32minline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (inline) 5.83 kB [1m[33m[entry][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mmain[39m[22m} [1m[32mmain.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (main) 8.54 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mpolyfills[39m[22m} [1m[32mpolyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (polyfills) 202 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mstyles[39m[22m} [1m[32mstyles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (styles) 11.4 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mvendor[39m[22m} [1m[32mvendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (vendor) 2.66 MB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
(node:18016) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.

webpack: Compiled successfully.
[21:43:45] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.34.zip
[21:43:45] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.34.zip
[21:43:45] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.34.exe up to date
[21:43:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:43:45] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Jasmine started

people-in-space API
    [31m× should report success getting a list of people in space[39m
    [31m- [39m[31mFailed: Cannot read property 'getComponentFromError' of null[39m
        at TestBed._initIfNeeded (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\packages\core\esm5\testing\src\test_bed.js:400:22)
        at TestBed.get (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core-testing.umd.js:1071:14)
        at Function.TestBed.get (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core-testing.umd.js:863:29)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\e2e\api.e2e-spec.ts:11:24)
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1067:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2396:12)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2860:25)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:388:26)
        at Zone.run (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:138:43)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:870:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:421:31)
    From: Task: Run beforeAll in control flow
        at Function.promise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\e2e\api.e2e-spec.ts:9:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\e2e\api.e2e-spec.ts:5:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Module.m._compile (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:392:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:395:12)
        at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    [31m- [39m[31mFailed: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined[39m
        at resetFakeAsyncZone (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core-testing.umd.js:401:19)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\packages\core\esm5\testing\src\before_each.js:25:12)
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1067:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2396:12)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2860:25)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:388:26)
        at Zone.run (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:138:43)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:870:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:421:31)
        at Zone.runTask (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:188:47)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:594:35)
    From: Task: Run beforeEach in control flow
        at ControlFlow.emit (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\events.js:62:21)
        at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2565:10)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core-testing.umd.js:1283:15
        at Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\tslib\tslib.es6.js:1:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core-testing.umd.js:10:2)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\e2e\api.e2e-spec.ts:1:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Module.m._compile (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:392:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:395:12)
    [31m- [39m[31mFailed: Cannot read property 'get' of null[39m
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\e2e\api.e2e-spec.ts:26:14)
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1067:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2396:12)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2860:25)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:388:26)
        at Zone.run (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:138:43)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:870:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:421:31)
        at Zone.runTask (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:188:47)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:594:35)
        at <anonymous>
    From: Task: Run it("should report success getting a list of people in space") in control flow
        at ControlFlow.emit (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\events.js:62:21)
        at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2565:10)
        at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2490:53)
        at MicroTask.asyncRun (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2619:9)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:388:26)
        at Zone.run (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:138:43)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:870:57
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\e2e\api.e2e-spec.ts:25:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\e2e\api.e2e-spec.ts:5:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Module.m._compile (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:392:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:395:12)
        at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

people-in-space App
    [31m× should display welcome message[39m
    [31m- [39m[31mFailed: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined[39m
        at resetFakeAsyncZone (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core-testing.umd.js:401:19)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\packages\core\esm5\testing\src\before_each.js:25:12)
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1067:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2396:12)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2860:25)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:388:26)
        at Zone.run (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:138:43)
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:870:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:421:31)
        at Zone.runTask (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:188:47)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:594:35)
    From: Task: Run beforeEach in control flow
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core-testing.umd.js:1283:15
        at Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\tslib\tslib.es6.js:1:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core-testing.umd.js:10:2)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\people-in-space\e2e\api.e2e-spec.ts:1:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Module.m._compile (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:392:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\git\people-in-space\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:395:12)

**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) people-in-space API should report success getting a list of people in space
[31m- [39m[31mFailed: Cannot read property 'getComponentFromError' of null[39m
[31m- [39m[31mFailed: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined[39m
[31m- [39m[31mFailed: Cannot read property 'get' of null[39m

2) people-in-space App should display welcome message
[31m- [39m[31mFailed: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined[39m

Executed 2 of 2 specs[31m (2 FAILED)[39m in 1 sec.
[21:43:49] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[21:43:49] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 2 test(s)
[21:43:49] I/launcher - overall: 2 failed spec(s)
[21:43:49] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! people-in-space@0.0.0 e2e: `ng e2e`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the people-in-space@0.0.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\akb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-04T21_43_49_504Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Your setup doesn't make sense. For one thing, it's not an E2E test; you're trying to call the backend directly. Protractor is not the tool for this job, and the HttpClient is designed to work in the context of an Angular application.

Comment: I agree this is not strictly an e2e test, but the alternative - calling it a unit-test, is even worse!  Thanks for making me look at the source code of HttpClient, @jonrsharpe.  Actually nothing about it assumes the context of an Angular application apart from the dependency injection.

Comment: I would refer to that as an *"integration test"* - and note that the specific client should not matter (if it *does*, you have a big problem!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered I can use HttpClient in an e2e test if I circumvent Angular's dependency injection.

`npm install xmlhttprequest`

**api.e2e-spec.ts**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpXhrBackend, XhrFactory, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { XMLHttpRequest} from 'xmlhttprequest';

export class BrowserXhr implements XhrFactory {
    constructor() {}
    build(): any { return <any>(new XMLHttpRequest()); }
}

describe('people-in-space API', () => {

    const http: HttpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpXhrBackend(new BrowserXhr()));

    it('should report success getting a list of people in space', (done) => {
        http.get('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json').subscribe((response: any) => {
            expect(response.message).toEqual('success');
            done();
        }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            done.fail(error.message);
        });
    });

});
```

[repo](https://github.com/Antony74/people-in-space/commit/633f9e295db40ed0b931b6235cd9b4f8846c4df7)